# Linear Algebra EigenVector and EigenValue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose the characteristic polynomial of a 3x3 matrix has 1 root at zero. What is the nullity
of this matrix? (Hint: Consider the diagonal form for the matrix. Write  in diagonal form as a
linear combination of rank 1 matrices formed from its eigenvectors. Two matrices get multiplied
by zero eigenvalues.) Can you determine the inverse of this matrix? What is the requirement on
the characteristic polynomial of a matrix for the matrix to be invertible?

How do I choose the matrix?

Comment: Hint :The characteristic polynomial is in form $\chi(t)=t\alpha(t)$, where $\alpha(t)$ is a second degree polynomial. If the polynomial has only one root in zero, then the Kernel won't be trivial since $\exists 0\ne v\in Ker f$ ($f$ is the map asscoiated ti your matrix).

Comment: @B The hint given is very strange; I would ignore it. Also, I don't understand what you mean by your question of "how do I choose the matrix".